# Online Web Service That Takes Data From Database In My PC

Tags: c#, sql, web-services

Hello I have a Web Service that connects to my local SQL Server 2008 and takes data from a table and then sends them to a WPF app i am testing.

As long as the Web Service is running from my PC everything runs nice and smooth. Now I want to upload this Web Service to a site i have so i can test the call online but i don't know what connection sting i must use so that the Web Service can locate my local SQL from internet when i call the web service.

Also do i have to make any change to my SQL to achieve this?

Comment: What's the point? If you have to expose the db on your local pc, why bother running the web service elsewhere?

Comment: Because I want to test the Web Service online but i cant find the way to do it

Comment: There is no harm in exposing your SQL sever JUST (I repeat: JUST) for test purposes, but you should never do that for the release. Now tell us about your internet connection and you network configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to use ngrok but i couldn't get past some problems
At the end i used a friends space in a web server for my tests thanks for your answers

Answer (score 0):

Ngrok is a good tool to do something like that. With ngrok you can create a tunnel from internet to your PC in specific port (database port). The only thing you need to change on connection string is the server parts, and point to url that ngrok gives to you.

[Ngrok website](http://ngrok.com)